# Autodesk Forge: BIM spaces and rooms in the Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there any way to find a list of IFC spaces and/or RVT rooms in the Forge viewer? I'm making a building simulation app and I'm looking for a way to allow users to select individual spaces/rooms to run their simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see this blog writen by Xiaodong Liang [Make shader face for room object of the model](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/make-shader-face-room-object-model)

Comment: "It is a pity Forge translator does not extract native Revit file in the format of level (floor), rooms, while Navisworks has the concept of rooms and brings this along when imported into Forge."

Are there any plans to add rooms translation from other bim formats like ifc/rvt? cc @XiaodongLiang